# Embed JavaScript in an e-book using an e-reader

Tags: ebook-readers, embedding

I'm looking for an e-reader that can embed Javascript in an e-book. I need to display a popup in the e-book but using a e-reader.

Apparently, it is [not possible for the Kindle Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167688/embed-javascript-in-a-kindle-ebook) but I'm wondering if it is possible with another device?

Comment: I need to load some information as a popup with some part of the text. The better solution will be Javascript but for now I've didn't find any device that embed JS.

Comment: I need to have javascript embedded in the ebook naturally and these javascript should be `used` in the e-reader device. My problem is to find a e-reader device that allow the use of Javascript.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I know that ePub3 allows JS development but for me I want to use these possibilities in an e-book loaded in an e-reader.

Comment: Welcome to Ebooks.SE by the way.

Comment: @Anthon thanks, my answer was unclear because for me it was clear that I need to use JS in ebook in the e-reader and not in any other app. Now it's clear ;-)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is an optional part of the [epub 3.0 specification](http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-contentdocs.html#sec-scripted-content-rs-reqs):

> EPUB Content Documents may contain scripting using the facilities
>   defined for this in the respective underlying specifications ([HTML5]
>   and [SVG]).

What this means is that even a fully-compliant epub 3.0 device doesn't need to implement JavaScript support. The ones that do will generally be the "more bells and whistles" devices; the iPad, for example, supports JavaScript. The IDPF's epub Chrome extension [Readium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/readium/fepbnnnkkadjhjahcafoaglimekefifl?hl=en-US) does as well.

Note that according to the [epub 3.0 specification](http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-contentdocs.html#sec-scripted-content-rs-reqs), the following criteria for reading systems that support JavaScript must be met:

> › It must support container-constrained scripting and may support
>   spine-level scripting.
>
> › It may render Scripted Content Documents as an interactive, scripted
>   User Agent according to [HTML5].
>
> › It must not allow a container-constrained script to modify the DOM
>   of the parent Content Document or other contents in the EPUB
>   Publication, and must not allow it to manipulate the size of its
>   containing rectangle. (Note: Even if a script is not
>   container-constrained, the Reading System may impose restrictions on
>   modifications (see also the dom-manipulation feature).)
>
> › It may place additional limitations on the capabilities provided to
>   scripts during execution (e.g., limiting networking).
>
> › It must implement the JavaScript navigator extension object
>   epubReadingSystem defined in Appendix A, JavaScript epubReadingSystem
>   Object . It also must support the dom-manipulation and layout-change
>   features defined in Features in container-constrained scripting
>   contexts.
>
> › It must regard the scripted [Publications301] property of the
>   Package Document manifest item element as the authoritative definition
>   of whether an EPUB Content Document includes scripting.

EDIT: Popup text and images are definitely possible using JavaScript in iBooks. For an example, check out [Beneath The Ink](https://beneaththeink.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Also Adobe Digital Editions 4.0 seems to reading JavaScript. It is rather important, because ADE is rendering engine for most e-readers for the market. Unfortunately not all (if any at all) manufacturers use new engine at this time.
ADE 4.0 is available on [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/digital-editions/download.html) sites

Comment: Which devices use ADE? Sony Reader use it or no?

Comment: I wasn't able to find any confirmation but you can safely assume that Sony use Adobe RMSDK. But Sony have abandon developing of any e-reading systems back in 2014 so you can't count Sony devices will be able to run any of JavaScript.

Comment: I'd not expect Sony devices to ever do JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for an e-reader that can embed Javascript.

AFAIK, only tablets with epub3 apps support Javascript.

For example, iPads/iPhones with iBooks and Android tablets with [Gitden Reader](http://gitden.com) (which is also available for iOS.)

Comment: I think pocketbook have some e-readers with RMSDK v.10 which could be able to run some JS but heavy testing is needed

Comment: AFAIK, scripting was introduced in RMSDK v.11 and none of the PocketBook models supports it.